# BSD sed: Replace only the Nth occurrence of a pattern

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression, freebsd, bsd

## *Using BSD `sed`;*

How can I perform the following substitution?:

Before:

```
hello hello hello
hello hello hello
```

After:

```
hello world hello
hello hello hello
```

In other words; how can I replace only *the* ***N***th *occurence* of a pattern?
(Or in this case; *the* ***2***nd *occurrence* of a pattern?)

Comment: I played with this for a bit.  Conclusion: You're much better off using GNU `sed` or Perl for this; there's no *general* way to do this reliably in BSD `sed`.  Even for a fixed string it's hard; for a complex regex it's probably impossible.  The following doesn't work: `sed 's/^\(hello.*\)hello/\1world/'`  Can you see why?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not always available. Also; I can't see why that *would* work. Although, you could just be using some RegEx tricks that I don't yet understand. However, I think you'll want the `-E` flag; i.e. `sed -E`.

Comment: If it's just a fixed string `hello hello hello` then you could just do `s/hello hello/hello world/'.

Comment: Related: [Using sed to replace *n*th occurrence of a word](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/587916/80216), [How to add text before the *N*th occurrence of a text using sed only?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/686576/80216), [sed or awk: replace only the n-th occurrence of a string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/702477/80216), [How to delete the n-th word from standard input?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/715933/80216), and [Print everything after nth delimiter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/650424/80216)

Answer (score 1):

With any POSIX `sed`:

```
$ sed -e'/hello/{' -e:1 -e'$!N;s/hello/world/2;t2' -eb1 -e\} -e:2 -en\;b2 <file
hello world hello
hello hello hello
```

- After the first match `/hello/`, we run into a loop.
- Inside loop `:1`, we read each `N`ext line to the pattern space, doing `s`ubstitute command for `2`nd occurrence only. We `t`est if the substitution success or not. If yes, we run into loop `:2`, else repeat the loop with `b1`.
- Inside loop `:2`, we just print remain lines till the end of file.

Note that this approach will store all things between two *hello* in pattern space. It will be a problem with huge files, when the first and the second are far from each other.

Answer (score -1):

It can be easier if you use two `sed`s. In fact, many things are, and they are often *faster* that way, as well, on multicore systems, at least.

```sh
:    infile =;<<"" \
sed -e's/$/ /;s/hello/&\n\n/g' -e'# marks lines with " $" and splits matches' |
sed -e:n   -e's/ $//;t'  -eG   -e'# sets up a test label, branches for " $"'  \
    -e's/o\n\{20\}$/o world/'  -e'# stacks a byte per match, edits nth match' \
    -e'x;N;x;N;s/\n\n*//;tn'   -e'# completes the stacking; recycles to top'  \
>outfile
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
```

---

```
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
hello hello world hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
```

*(With a BSD `sed` you'll want a literal newline in place of the `n` for the `\n` escapes in the right-hand substitution field)*

It is usually easier to adapt the stream than to adapt the stream editor. The above sequence does just that: it marks each whole line in input with a trailing space, but otherwise splits output lines for each occurrence of *`hello`*. The second `sed` then needs only to look for a line which does not end in space to know that it should increment its stack count, and then only to explicitly match the 20th.

Of course it doesn't have to be that strict. You could drop the leading *`o`* before `\n\{20\}$` and leave it off the replacement. That would replace only *from* the 20th match through to the last in input. Or else you could do `\n\{20,25\}` to handle only a range of matches. Or even: `\n\{20,25\}\(\n\{15\}\)*$` to handle a range of 20,25 and every 10,15th occurrence thereafter.

Here's an output sample given the same input for that last mentioned...

---

```
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
hello hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world hello hello
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello world hello world
hello world hello world hello world hello world hello hello hello hello hello
hello hello hello hello hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world
hello world hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
```