# Using sed to replace nth occurrence of a word

Tags: sed

I am learning sed, so in this context I am trying to replace 2nd occurrence of word 'line'. Therefore, I issued following command:

```
(zet:pc:~/text) sed 's/line/LINUX/2' mytextfile
this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 3
this is line 4
this is line 5
```

But from the output, you can see that 'sed' is not replacing 2nd occurrence of the world 'line'.  So, am I making any mistake here?

Comment: It would be great if you could clarify what you mean by the *word* ‘‘word’’.  For example, if the file contains “linear” or “spline”, would you want them changed to “LINUXar” or “spLINUX”, or should those words be skipped?

Comment: Related: [How to add text before the *N*th occurrence of a text using sed only?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/686576/80216),  [sed or awk: replace only the n-th occurrence of a string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/702477/80216),  [How to delete the n-th word from standard input?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/715933/80216),  [BSD sed: Replace only the *N*th occurrence of a pattern](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/254402/80216), and [Print everything after nth delimiter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/650424/80216).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`s/../../2` replaces the second occurrence on each line.

You can make it work if you read the file as *one* line:

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -z 's/line/LINUX/2' mytextfile
```

With normal `sed`:

```
tr '\n' '\0' < mytextfile  |  sed 's/line/LINUX/2'  |  tr '\0' '\n'
```

Note that this will produce incorrect results
in the ***highly** unlikely* case that the file *already* contains nul bytes.

---

To replace the first occurrence on the 2nd line, see other answers :-)

Comment: Doing this removed everything after the occurrence on my JSON file.

Comment: `\z` is the `z` char, `\0` is the null char

Answer (score 5):

In your file, the second occurrence is on the second line so what you need is this:

```
sed '2s/line/LINUX/' mytextfile
```

To edit the file in-place:

```
sed -i '2s/line/LINUX/' mytextfile
```

The `2s` is to make the change on the second line. Your command would only work if the string `line` appeared more than once on one or more lines.

Comment: OP asks for *replace 2nd occurrence*,  not first occurrence on 2nd line.

Comment: @pLumo why not? This is exactly what the OP is asking for, isn't it? This will replace the word `line` on the second line. It produces the same output as your `-z` approach but is more portable and doesn't require reading the entire file as a single line.

Comment: It does the same for **that** piece of text, but it is till not what OP is asking for. Especially considering "I am learning sed".

Comment: @pLumo I guess it depends on how you read the question. I read it as the OP misunderstanding what the `/2` does, since they clearly expected it to make the change on the second line. Good to have both approaches, anyway.

Comment: Fair enough ;-) I added a note to my answer.

Comment: @pLumo I understand, but according to the contents of the file, the second occurrence of the string `line` is, in fact, on the second line. As terdon stated, he clearly wanted the change to occur on the second line and my answer provides that. It does the exact same thing as your answer and I even provided the case where the command that he was using would work.

Comment: I disagree with "*he clearly wanted the change to occur on the second line*", but as @terdon has said: "*Good to have both approaches*" ;-)

Comment: @pLumo Where else in the file would he have possibly wanted it to occur? That string only appears once on each line. Had it appeared more than once on each line then his command would have worked and there wouldn't have been any need for him to ask the question.

Comment: OP says he's learning, so I guess the text is just an example.

Comment: Worked perfectly for my particular scenario my required line number. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For Line parsing , you should mention the line number preceding the command 's'

```
$ echo "this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 3
this is line 4
this is line 5" | sed -e '2s/line/LINUX/'
this is line 1
this is LINUX 2
this is line 3
this is line 4
this is line 5
```

So, for you the command is :

```
sed -e '2s/line/LINUX/' mytextfile
```

And yes , if regardless of line number , if you want to just replace the 2nd occurrence in the whole file , pLumo's answer is right.

```
sed -z 's/line/LINUX/2' mytextfile
```

Comment: OP asks for *replace 2nd occurrence*,  not first occurrence on 2nd line.