# Print everything after nth delimiter

Tags: bash, text-processing

How do I print the remainder of a string (not just the columns without the delimiter) after the nth delimiter?

I have a text file with a bunch of registry keys, similar to:

```
hku\test\user\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\runonce\delete cached update binary
```

I'm wanting to print everything after the 3rd `\` character. So I am looking for the output to be

```
software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\runonce\delete cached update binary
```

I know how to print out specific columns with `awk`, but is there any simple way using `bash` to specify a delimiter to split the string at, instead of using the delimiter to print columns?

Comment: Related: [Using sed to replace *n*th occurrence of a word](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/587916/80216), [How to add text before the *N*th occurrence of a text using sed only?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/686576/80216), [sed or awk: replace only the n-th occurrence of a string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/702477/80216), [How to delete the n-th word from standard input?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/715933/80216) and [BSD sed: Replace only the *N*th occurrence of a pattern](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/254402/80216)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pipe through  `cut -d \\ -f 4-`.

```
echo 'hku\test\user\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\runonce\delete cached update binary' | cut -d \\ -f 4-
```

Yields:

```
software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\runonce\delete cached update binary
```

Note the double `\\`, since a single `\` is an escape character.

Comment: Alternatively, you can quote the `\` to avoid escaping: `cut -d '\' -f 4-`

Answer (score 6):

With `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/^([^\]*[\]){3}//' infile
```

or the same in `awk`:

```
awk '{ sub(/([^\\]*[\\]){3}/, "") }1' infile
```

Match repeated of `(regex)` 3times; `[^\]*[\]` matches on zero-or-more of any-characters but not a back-slash (plus not a newline exceptionally) followed by a back-slash character.

---

And the shell (POSIX sh/bash/Korn/zsh) solution:

```
$ str='hku\test\user\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\runonce\delete cached update binary'
$ for i in $(seq 3); do str="${str#*\\}"; done
$ printf '%s\n' "$str"
```

The `${parameter#word}` syntax is the [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), that strips the shortest prefix from its parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`:

```bsh
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\\"; }{for(i=4;i<NF;i++) printf "%s", $i OFS; print $NF }' input
```

Because we want to print everything after the 3rd `\` character, Field separaror `FS` and output field separator `OFS` are set to `\`. `FS="\\"` because single `\` is escape character.
Because `\` is now filed separator we use a for loop to print from filed number 4 to last field of record.

Or like this:

```bsh
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\\"; }{for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s", $i (i==NF?ORS:OFS) }' input
```

Here everything is same but ternary operator is used. Here for loop will print `OFS` after `$i` for all but last field. After last field this will print `ORS` i.e. a newline.

Another method:

```bsh
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\\"} { n=split($0,arr,OFS); $0=""; for (i=4; i<=n; ++i) $(i-3)=arr[i]; print }' input
```

Here  `split()` built-in function splits `$0` by `OFS` and creates an array `arr`. Then for loop changes every field of record by `$(i-3)=arr[i]`. For example for first element of for loop, `$1` will be arr[4]. Why `$1` because `$(4-3)` is `$1`. When loop is completed `awk` has a new `$0` that starts from fourth field of old record (`$0`). Then print command prints new `$0`.

Answer (score 2):

```
## input variables
n=3
s='hku\test\user\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\runonce\delete cached update binary'
```

**sed**
Change the n-th backslash to a newline, a character known to not be present, we then strip away everything till the newline.

```
printf '%s\n' "$s" |
sed -e '
  s/\\/\n/'"$n"'
  s/.*\n//
' -
software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\runonce\delete cached update binary
```

---

**linux command line**
Convert to one-field per line, chop off the first n fields, and then join them back.

```
printf '%s\n' "$s" | tr '\\' '\n' | tail -n+"$((n+1))" | paste -sd '\\' -
```

---

**bash builtins**

```
set -f;IFS=\\;
declare -a a=( $s )
printf '%s\n' "${a[*]:$n}"
```

---

**awk**

```
printf '%s\n' "$s" |
awk -F '\' -v n="$n" '
NF>n {
  for (i=p=1; i<=n; i++) 
    p += 1+length($i)
  $0 = substr($0,p)
}1' -
```

---

```
printf '%s\n' "$s" |
perl -pals -F'/\\/,$_,$n+1' -e '
  $_=$F[-1];
' -- -n="$n"  -
```

---

```
python3 -c 'import sys
p,(s,n) = -1,sys.argv[1:]
for i in range(1+int(n)):
  p = 1+s.find("\\",p)
print(s[p:])
' "$s" "$n"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to not miss `perl`:

```
perl -e '@a=split /\\/, $ARGV[0]; print(join("\\", splice @a, 3), "\n")' $str
```

Where `str` is the path.

Or without the endings new line :

```
perl -e '@a=split /\\/, $ARGV[0]; print join "\\", splice @a, 3' $str
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F"\\" '{ OFS="\\"; $1=$2=$3=""; sub(/\\*/,""); print }' filename
```

output

```
software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\runonce\delete cached update binary
```

Comment: Since the solution here is to hard-code the first N fields by setting them to an empty string in the awk script, you might want to mention that in case the next person wants to use this with something like N=50.

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).