# sed or awk: replace only the n-th occurence of a string

Tags: bash, awk, sed

How to write a `sed` (or `awk`, or both) which will take the following:

```
echo '1 aa 2 2 3 bb 5 bb 2 5' | sed/awk ...
```

And only replace the n-th occurrence of a string? For example the 3rd occurrence of `2` or the second occurrence of `bb`?

So the expected output would be (when replacing 2nd occurrence of `bb` with `replaced` for example):

```
1 aa 2 2 3 bb 5 replaced 2 5
```

The input string, the replacement string, and `n` can be any arbitrary input.

Comment: do you want to change `abb bb bb` into `abb CHG bb` or `abb bb CHG` (?) when it's a change of the second match of the string `bb`. I. e, do you want strings as if they are a word boundaries or partial match like in `abb`?

Comment: And what about `bbbb`? You can argue, that the first and second `b` form the first `bb` and the second and third form the second `bb` (-> `bBBb`). The `sed` interpretation is non-overlapping matches, so the third and forth `b` form the second match (-> `bbBB`)

Comment: @αғsнιη not sure why you sent this ("see also..."). My question was only asked two days ago. I am quite busy both professionally and personally and my Sundays are for God. Furthermore, I feel that my description was clear enough. The answer to your questions are already in my post: `The input string, the replacement string, and n can be any (sensical) arbitrary input.`. As such, it is partial/exact match.

Comment: @Philippos thank you for the question. If the string was `bbbb` and `b` was searched for then we would have 4 occurrences. If the `bb` was searched for then we would have 2 max occurrences (one could say that as soon as the first `bb` was found, it would be replaced). Also, search/replace should not be recursive (for example where the replace string would be `bbb` etc.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using sed to replace nth occurrence of a word](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/587916/using-sed-to-replace-nth-occurrence-of-a-word)

Comment: Related: [How to add text before the *N*th occurrence of a text using sed only?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/686576/80216),  [How to delete the n-th word from standard input?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/715933/80216),  [BSD sed: Replace only the *N*th occurrence of a pattern](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/254402/80216)  and  [Print everything after nth delimiter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/650424/80216)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `sed` to change the second occurance of `bb`

```
$ sed 's/bb/new-bb/2' file
1 aa 2 2 3 bb 5 new-bb 2 5
```

or to change the third occurance of 2

```
$ sed 's/2/12/3' file
1 aa 2 2 3 bb 5 bb 12 5
```

Comment: I did not know there was an option like this in `sed`. Simple and beautiful, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

To change the n<sup>th</sup> occurrence within a line, `sed` has syntax for that with `s/pattern/replacement/3` as [already shown by @HatLess](/a/702480).

To change the n<sup>th</sup> occurrence in the whole input, you could use `perl` with:

```
perl -pse 'if($n>0) {s{pattern}{--$n ? $& : "replacement"}ge}' -- -n=3
```

Answer (score 2):

With `awk` you could do:

```
awk -v str='bb' -v pos=2 -v rplc='newBB' '
 {
   strPos=0
   for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
       if($i==str && (++strPos==pos) ) { $i=rplc; break }
 }1' infile
```

Output:

```
1 aa 2 2 3 bb 5 newBB 2 5
```

---

Note: Above it assumes that there is only a sinlge character as the field separator (defualt: Space or Tab) since otherwise consecutive field separator will squeeze into one or you can force awk to match on each single field separator separately (so the FS must be forced as regex mode):

```
awk -F'[\t]' -v OFS='\t' -v str='bb' -v pos=2 -v rplc='newBB' '
 {
   strPos=0
   for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
      if($i==str && (++strPos==pos) ) { $i=rplc; break }
 }1' infile
```

Note: change `\t` to Space character if the field seperator is Space chartacter.

---

To change the n<sup>th</sup> occurrence in the whole input (yet I assumed field seperator is the Tab character):

```
awk -F'[\t]' -v OFS='\t' -v str='bb' -v pos=2 -v rplc='newBB' '
 strPos!=2{
            for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
                if($i==str && (++strPos==pos) ) { $i=rplc; break }
 }1' infile
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there an extra `'` at the end of the first line?

Comment: @RoelVandePaar you are welcome! and no, that is not extra.

Comment: @RoelVandePaar  The `awk` program is formatted multi-line for clarity, and the matching quote is on the last line.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I like the simplicity of the `sed` but this is a valuable extra on `awk` to learn from.

Answer (score 2):

We can do both with `sed` in a single command:

```
echo "1 aa 2 2 3 bb 5 bb 2 5"|sed -e "s/2/kop/3" -e "s/bb/pp/2"
```

This command will replace 3rd occurrence of `2` with `kop` and 2nd occurrence of `bb` with `pp`.