# How to delete the n-th word from standard input?

Tags: text-processing

I want to create a script that deletes the N<sup>th</sup> word from the standard input, for a given N. For example, for this input:

```
One two three four, five
six seven eight, nine
```

If we ask to delete the 8th word, it should delete the `eight,`. For my purposes, a word is any sequence of non-space characters.

```
One two three four, five
six seven  nine
```

Is there some clever one-liner that can accomplish this using standard command line utilities? Currently I have a fairly long script to do this,
but it feels like overkill.

Comment: Does your real file has only two lines? I believe not... is better to update the question with more data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using sed to replace nth occurrence of a word](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/587916/using-sed-to-replace-nth-occurrence-of-a-word)

Comment: Related: [How to add text before the *N*th occurrence of a text using sed only?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/686576/80216),  [sed or awk: replace only the n-th occurrence of a string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/702477/80216),  [BSD sed: Replace only the *N*th occurrence of a pattern](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/254402/80216) and [Print everything after nth delimiter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/650424/80216)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `perl`:

```
$ perl -pe 's/\S+/++$c == 8 ? "" : $&/ge' <your-file
One two three four, five
six seven  nine
```

```
$ perl -pse 's/\S+/--$n ? $& : ""/ge' -- -n=8 <your-file
One two three four, five
six seven  nine
```

Or optimising a bit and not perform the `s`ubstitutions once the n<sup>th</sup> word has been found:

```
perl -pse 's/\S+/--$n ? $& : ""/ge if $n > 0' -- -n=8 <your-file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk and without reading all of the input into memory at once:

```
$ awk -v t=8 '{p=n; n+=NF} (n>t) && !f++{$(t-p)=""} 1' file
One two three four, five
six seven  nine
```

Comment: Would be worth noting that it may affect the spacing in the line with the word to remove as sequences of one or more whitespace characters are turned into one space and the leading and trailing whitespace are removed.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -Ez 's/(([^ \n]*( |\n)){7})[^ ]*/\1/' input_file
One two three four, five
six seven  nine
```

Comment: Hmm... what does this do that the naive `sed -z 's/[^[:space:]]\{1,\}//8'` doesn't?

Comment: Since `-z` for reading the whole file into memory requires GNU sed you could also take advantage of other GNU-isms and abbreviate that to `sed -Ez 's/\S+//8'`

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution with awk:

```
awk 'n>0 && n<=NF {$n=""} {n-=NF} 1' n=8 infile
```

If you need to re-adjust the white spaces (as one field has been removed, two consecutive FS appear).

```
$ awk 'n>0 && n<=NF {$n="";gsub(/[ \t]+/, " ")} {n-=NF} 1' n=8 infile

One two three four, five
six seven nine
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses GNU sed's `-z` feature, which reads the whole file as a "single line"

```
sed -Ez 's/\S+//8'
```

Alternatively, to also remove the spaces following that word

```
sed -Ez 's/\S+ *//8'
```

Credit goes to Ed Morton, who posted this [as a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/133219/ed-morton) to another answer.